# How can I write a controller in a Spring Boot JSON query?

Tags: json, spring-boot

How can I build a query parameter in Spring Boot such that I can retrieve
http://localhost:9010/data?meta=part1&meta=part2 to show only two parts of the JSON data?

```html
{
"part1": [
"abc",
"asd",

],
"part2": [
"er",
"rt",
"df"
],
}
```

The complete result is:

```html
    {
    "part1": [
    "abc",
    "asd",

    ],
    "part2": [
    "er",
    "rt",
    "df"
    ],
    "part3": [
    "fdgdgd",
    "fdgfdg",
    "xcvcxv"

    ],
    "part4": [
    "qweqwe",
    "bvnbvn"
    ],
}
```

UPDATE: I have already completed the /GET for service IN SPRINGBOOT controller which shows the complete result as above

Now i want to fetch only that data (ex URL http://localhost:9010/data?meta=**part1**&meta=**part2**  fetches only part1 and part2 )

How can i build the part after /data?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide your Java code to show what you have done.

Comment: I have already got the complete result .I just want to know how can I retrieve result http://localhost:9010/data?meta=part1&meta=part2  on this .I can update the code

Comment: where you get complete result?

Comment: you mean you received data in controller?

Comment: Can you make the controller's last arguments a varargs?  This should allow you to pass in any number of 'meta' params

Comment: Since there is nothing apparently related to Java in your post, in my edit suggestion, I removed that tag and switched it with a JSON tag, as it is used in your post.

Comment: varargs how can I pass in controller  any example?